# Finding inorder successor of a BST in C

Tags: algorithm, c, binary-search, binary-search-tree

### Please review this code

I have written a function to find the successor of BST in c. It takes three arguments, i.e root pointer to the binary search tree, node value of which we have to find a successor and parent pointer (for first call it is also root pointer. It will return an integer that is the successor of the node value give.

```
/**
 * find Successor of BST, complex: o(h)
 * @param rootPtr root pointer of BST
 * @param parent_node parent node of the subtree (root node should be passed by default)
 * @param nodeValue node val to find successor
 * @return succsor
 */
int find_successor_h(BSTNode * rootPtr, int data, BSTNode * parent_node) {
  if (rootPtr == NULL) return data;
  int rt;

  if (data < rootPtr -> data)
    rt = find_successor_h(rootPtr -> left_child, data, rootPtr);
  else if (data > rootPtr -> data)
    rt = find_successor_h(rootPtr -> right_child, data, rootPtr);
  else {
    if (rootPtr -> right_child != NULL)
      return minBST(rootPtr -> right_child);
    else if (rootPtr != parent_node)
      return INT_MIN;
    else
      return data;
  }

  if (rt == INT_MIN)
    return INT_MAX;

  if (rt == INT_MAX)
    return parent_node -> data;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a test program that drives this?  It is easier to review if we can compile and run for ourselves, and for that we need a definition of `BSTNode`.

Comment: The `minBST` function is also missing.

Comment: Abrar Ajaz Wani, Please post enough code so one may compile it.  It is not necessary to link it - but that would even be better.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3):

**Missing return**

Code may even fail the last `rt == INT_MAX` and then no return is specified.

```
  if (rt == INT_MAX)
    return parent_node -> data;

  // Missing return.
  }
```

**Use `const`**

Using `const`, as able, provides more information as to what the code does and does not do.  This also allows greater usage and potential optimization.

```
// int find_successor_h(BSTNode * rootPtr, int data, BSTNode * parent_node) {
int find_successor_h(const BSTNode * rootPtr, int data, const BSTNode * parent_node) {
```

**Mis-matched comments**

Comment does not match parameter names nor order: `node val` vs.  `data`.

```
* @param rootPtr root pointer of BST
* @param parent_node parent node of the subtree (root node should be passed by default)
* @param nodeValue node val to find successor

BSTNode * rootPtr, int data, BSTNode * parent_node
```

**Missing include**

`NULL` not defined.

**Spelling**

`* @return succsor` vs. `* @return successor`

**Name error?**

Why `h` in `int find_successor_h()`?

**`{ block }`**

Consider using `{}` even for simple blocks.  Little need for `else`

```
//if (rootPtr -> right_child != NULL)
//  return minBST(rootPtr -> right_child);
//else if (rootPtr != parent_node)
//  return INT_MIN;
//else
// return data;

if (rootPtr -> right_child != NULL) {
  return minBST(rootPtr -> right_child);
}
if (rootPtr != parent_node) {
  return INT_MIN;
}
return data;
```

---

**Deeper review**

More support and test drive code needed for a deeper review.